# Listener for the button of external Layout

Tags: java, android, button, user-interface, listener

Hello I have a project in which one `Activity` and several `layout`. In the layouts contain various elements, such as buttons. I can not add buttons to these listeners from the main `Activity`. The `method onClick()` is used in the Activity (Activity implements `View.OnClickListener`)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
//....
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FrameLayout mainLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View one = (View) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.one, null);

        flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlip);

        int layouts[] = new int[]{R.layout.one, R.layout.two, R.layout.three};
        for (int layout : layouts) {
            flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null));
        }


        conBut = (Button) one.findViewById(R.id.conBut2);
        conBut.setOnClickListener(new listen());
    }


    private class listen implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          // ....
        }
    }

   //....
}
```

The result is a button, without action. Please, help me.

UPD1:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            fromPosition = event.getX();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            float toPosition = event.getX();
            if ((fromPosition - MOVE_LENGTH) > toPosition) {
                fromPosition = toPosition;
                flipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.go_next_in));
                flipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.go_next_out));
                flipper.showNext();
            } else if ((fromPosition + MOVE_LENGTH) < toPosition) {
                fromPosition = toPosition;
                flipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.go_prev_in));
                flipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.go_prev_out));
                flipper.showPrevious();
            }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

UPD2

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {
private class listen implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        makeMsg("Hello from onClick!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.conBut2: {
                makeMsg("Hello by Button2!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                case R.id.regRad: {
                    makeMsg("Hello by RadioButton!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
            }
            ;
            break;


        }
    }
}

    private void makeMsg(String txt, int dur) {
        Toast.makeText(this, txt, dur).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the question. Can you be more clear?

Comment: (Activity implements View.OnClickListener) ??? public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener ???

Comment: No, Activity implements OnTouchListener for ViewFlipper.
Listen class implements OnClickListener, which is processed and click event

Comment: I need to assign a listener for the button. The code above does not lead to a proper result.

Comment: How have you implemented public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) in you activity?

Comment: use the main activities onClick Listener, if you add the code that is in that listener, i can do it for you

Comment: Implementation `onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)`  is UPD1

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not add the entire `public void onClick (View view)` because of its volume. In UPD2 added his exemplary structure.

Comment: Please clarify `The code above does not lead to a proper result.` Is the onClick method do not fire?

Comment: Yes, that's right, the listener is not even called as if elements are simply imposed on the designer. Although, conBut is a real object - verified in the debugger. Logically, should be called onClick (), but this is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises because the `OnTouchListener` catch all touch events also Click.

In OnTouch

change

```
return true;
```

to

```
return false;
```

So, the event it is not consumed and is propagated to other listeners